# SQL query for last consecutive same data

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have data in a table like

```
+----+------------+------+
| Id | data_date  | data |
+----+------------+------+
|  1 | 01/01/2017 |    1 |
|  1 | 01/02/2017 |    0 |
|  1 | 01/03/2017 |    0 |
|  1 | 01/04/2017 |    0 |
|  2 | 01/02/2017 |    0 |
|  2 | 01/03/2017 |    0 |
|  2 | 01/04/2017 |    1 |
|  2 | 01/05/2017 |    1 |
+----+------------+------+
```

Data column only have values 0 and 1

How can i get last days consecutive same data type i.e. '0' or '1' for each ID

```
+----+-----------+-----------------+
| Id | data_Type | Last_Data_Count |
+----+-----------+-----------------+
|  1 |         0 |               3 |
|  2 |         1 |               2 |
+----+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, the RDBMS makes a difference. Does it matter if there are gaps between dates?

Comment: It makes a huge difference since your question smells like a gaps and islands problem.  MySQL has no (built in) analytic functions, so it would probably be harder to do with MySQL than Oracle.

Comment: Why not stick with plain ANSI SQL?

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX( last_data ) AS data_type, 
       COUNT(*) AS last_data_count
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         MAX ( CASE WHEN data <> last_data THEN data_date END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS last_date
  FROM   (
    SELECT d.*,
           MAX( data ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY data_date )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY id ) AS last_data
    FROM   data d
  ) d
)
WHERE  data_date > last_date
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need count of `data` of `max(data_date)` per `id`, you can try this. It should work on almost all RDBMS.

**[Rexter Sample for MYSQL](http://rextester.com/ISJ15270)**

```
select t3.id
    ,max(data) as data_type
    ,count(data) as last_data_count
    from table t3
    where exists
        (select 1 from Table t1
            where exists  
            (select 1 from table t2
             where t1.id=t2.id
             group by t2.id
             having t1.data_date=max(t2.data_date)
             ) 
     and t1.id=t3.id and t1.data=t3.data
)
group by t3.id
;
```

Explanation: Inner `exists` is used to get last data_date for each `id` based on `max(date)`. Now to get the count, I used outer `exists` to match `id` and `data` and then `group by` `id` to get count.

Comment: I didnt knew about **Rextester** seems like a great tool, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily obtained in **Oracle** by using [Tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) and then grouping the results, like so (N.B.: I am assuming you mean that by "last days consecutive" you mean consecutive rows, not consecutive dates):

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 1 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, to_date('01/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 0 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, to_date('01/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 0 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, to_date('01/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 0 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 0 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, to_date('01/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 0 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, to_date('01/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 1 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, to_date('01/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 1 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 0 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, to_date('01/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 1 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, to_date('01/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 0 DATA FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, to_date('01/05/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') data_date, 0 DATA FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking data in a table called "sample_data"
-- see below for the main SQL query:
SELECT ID,
       DATA,
       COUNT(*) last_data_count
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               data_date,
               DATA,
               MAX(data_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) max_data_date,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY data_date)
                 - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DATA ORDER BY data_date) grp
        FROM   sample_data)
GROUP BY ID,
         DATA,
         grp,
         max_data_date
HAVING   max_data_date = MAX(data_date);

        ID       DATA LAST_DATA_COUNT
---------- ---------- ---------------
         1          0               3
         2          1               2
         3          0               2
```

The tabibitosan part (i.e. `row_number() over (<overall set of data>) - row_number() over (<subset of data>)`) creates a group number for each set of consecutive rows (by which I mean rows that are next to each other in the specified order - *not* rows with consecutive dates) that have the same value in the data column.

Once you have obtained this, it's easy to find the counts over each set of consecutive rows. However, since you were after the latest count, I used the `MAX()` analytic function to find the latest data_date for each id.

Then, we can compare the max data_date for each set of consecutive rows, and use that to find the set of consecutive rows that matches the max data_date for the id (which we do in the `having` clause). Voila!

Comment: Thank you **Boneist** for the explanation and query it was really helpful, and thank you to everyone else as well
Btw I am using oracle.